# How to image an internal HDD attached with a usb adapter, then restore image?

Tags: hard-drive, backup

My laptop is going into repairs and I don't trust the warranty company not to wipe/ruin my data.  I've plugged my drive into my girlfriend's laptop via an Apricon SATA 2.5" adapter.  I'd like to create an image, then use the image to reimage my drive if it comes back blank.  I'm running Windows 8.

What I see online about imaging drives seems to refer mainly to the internal drive running within the laptop in use, though, or imaging that internal drive *to* an external drive.

How can I back up the image of my laptop's drive -- and then restore from that backup if/when the time comes -- instead of just moving over its files?

I'm currently trying out Macrium Reflect.

Comment: When you clone a disk, the hd can not be mounted or the os running. Creating an image, the os can be running and hd mounted... or not. I am not sure with Reflect though. Personally I would just do a simple windows backup (files & image), and do a clone by getting the exact same hd and then use clonezilla. Send the cloned hd to the warranty people.

Comment: +1 Logman. I would do precisely that also. CloneZilla the Win 8 box to the external USB then send the original disk off. You can then clone the image back to start precisely where you left off. Win 8: Disable "Secure Boot" to boot to USB or CD for CloneZilla